# Python for Blender. Вызов метода из другого метода того же класса

Tags: python, классы, blender

Сразу скажу, Питон я не знаю, только самые азы.

Удалось написать такой клас

```
bl_info = {
        "name": "Outliner sorting",
        "version": (1, 1),
        "blender": (2, 80, 0),
        "author": "Igor Yuchimenko"
        } 

import bpy

class OutlinerSort(bpy.types.Operator):
  """Tooltip"""
  bl_idname = "outliner.sort"
  bl_label = "Sort alphabetic"
  
  def sort_collection(collection, case = False):

    if collection.children is None: return

    children = sorted (
      collection.children, 
      key = lambda c: c.name if case else c.name.lower()
    )

    for child in children:  
      collection.children.unlink(child)
      collection.children.link(child)
      sort_collection(child)
  
  
  def execute(self, context):

    for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
      sort_collection(scene.collection, False)
   
    return {'FINISHED'}
    


def draw_method(self, context):
  self.layout.operator(OutlinerSort.bl_idname)
 
def register():
  bpy.utils.register_class(OutlinerSort)
  bpy.types.OUTLINER_MT_context_menu.prepend(draw_method)

def unregister():
  bpy.types.OUTLINER_MT_context_menu.remove(draw_method)
  bpy.utils.unregister_class(OutlinerSort)
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

При нажатии на кнопку меню происходит вызов `execute`, а уже из этого метода нужная функция сортировки. Блендер выкидывает ошибку, что `sort_collection` не существует, но если заменить на `self.sort_collection(scene.collection, False)` появляется другая ошибка, что указано 3 аргумента вместо 2, когда я добавил `sort_collection(self, collection, case = False)` опять получаю ошибку, что метода не существует. Что не так? С другими языками я такого поведения не встречал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def sort_collection(collection, case = False):` должна принимать первым аргументом `self`, то есть как у тебя `def execute(self, context):` принимает первым `self`.

По сути тебе нужно написать:

```
... def sort_collection(self, collection, case = False):...\
```

И вызвать нужно в `execute`

```
self.sort_collection(collection, case)
```